# Can I use queryselector outside of the main function in dart?

Tags: dart

In many examples I see code like this:

```
InputElement task;

void main() {
  task = querySelector('#task');
  task.text = "blabla";
}
```

Doing it like this seems to have the same effect.

```
InputElement task = querySelector('#task');

void main() {
  task.text = "blabla";
}
```

I prefer the second way, but I'm not sure if there is any difference, or that the second way may break something.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can call querySelector at the top level.

However note the order of evaluation, as the DOM must be initialised first. Typically the dart script tag is placed at the end of the body, so main runs after the DOM has been created.

For a top level variable, the expression on the right hand side is evaluated when the variable is used the first time.

Consider the following example, which prints 1, 2, 3.

```
int i = foo();

foo() {
  print('#2');
  return 42;
}

main() {
 print('#1');
 int k = i;  // i is accessed for the first time, so foo() is called.
 print('#3');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Dart code isn't executed until the DOM is ready, both approaches work fine, and neither will break.